# Can this be optimized without using a global variable?

Tags: ruby, global-variables

I've recently begun learning ruby and I'm trying to avoid using global variables where possible. I wrote the below program which accepts user input and outputs math tables of the users choice (currently just +, * but to be expanded upon). I'm following suggestions from https://adriann.github.io/programming_problems.html to get me learning.

```
class User_input
    .
     # multiply
     def User_input.mult1_to_12
      by = (0..12).each do | range |
        result =  $choice_int * range
        puts "#{$choice_int} x #{range} = #{result}"
      end
    end

# add
def User_input.add1_to_12
  add = (0..12).each do | range |
    result = $choice_int + range
  puts "#{$choice_int} + #{range} = #{result}"
  end
end

# accepts user input
puts "Please enter the tables you require (1-12): "
  $choice_int = gets.to_i
  puts "You have selected #{$choice_int}"
  puts "Which tables do you require (+ - * /): "
  choice_method = gets.chomp
  puts "the method you have chosen is #{choice_method}"

  if choice_method == "*"
    User_input.mult1_to_12
  elsif
    choice_method == "+"
    add1_to_12
  end
end
```

You will note that I am currently using a global variable for `$choice`. Can someone with more experience suggest a more optimal solution. Please feel free to tear my code apart : ) Thanks.

Comment: Your question is better suited to SO's sister site, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), where you can get useful advice on how to improve working code. The purpose of SO is to provide help on fixing broken code and to provide suggestions for how to accomplish a given task. Moreover, at Code Review you will tend to get more detailed explanations of the reasons for approaching the problem in a particular way.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the tip Cary. Will take a look at Code Review.

Comment: "Can this be done in a more optimal way?" implies that your code is already optimal, so by definition it cannot be improved. (-: and |-:.

Comment: [codereview.se] is only for working code, which this one is not. Even without taking a hard look at it, let alone running it, I can already spot  at least two bugs, just by skimming it. There is an obvious `SyntaxError` on line 2 and a semantic error on the third-to-last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods can accept parameters, for example:

```
# add numbers
def add(a,b)
  a+b
end

puts add(1,2)
# will output 3
```

Here's a simple modification to your code using parameters:

```
class UserInput
  # multiply
  def self.mult1_to_12(choice_int)
    (0..12).each do | range |
      result =  choice_int * range
      puts "#{choice_int} x #{range} = #{result}"
    end
  end

  # add
  def self.add1_to_12(choice_int)
    (0..12).each do | range |
      result = choice_int + range
      puts "#{choice_int} + #{range} = #{result}"
    end
  end
end

# accepts user input
puts "Please enter the tables you require (1-12): "
choice_int = gets.to_i
puts "You have selected #{choice_int}"
puts "Which tables do you require (+ - * /): "
choice_method = gets.chomp
puts "the method you have chosen is #{choice_method}"

if choice_method == "*"
  UserInput.mult1_to_12(choice_int)
elsif choice_method == "+"
  UserInput.add1_to_12(choice_int)
end
```

And here's a bit prettier solution that can also handle - and / (and a bunch of other operations provided by Ruby's Fixnum):

```
class UserInputProcessor
  # define accessors to instance variables
  attr_accessor :choice_int, :choice_method 

  def process
    (0..12).map do |range|
      if choice_method.eql?('/')
        next if range.eql?(0) # need to skip X/0 to avoid division by zero
        range = range.to_f    # need to convert range to float to get float results
      end
      "#{choice_int} #{choice_method} #{range.to_i} = #{choice_int.send(choice_method, range)}"
    end
  end
end

handler = UserInputProcessor.new

print "Please enter the tables you require (1-12): "
handler.choice_int = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "You have selected #{handler.choice_int}"

print "Which tables do you require (+ - * /): "
handler.choice_method = gets.chomp
puts "the method you have chosen is #{handler.choice_method}"
puts "And here are the results:"
puts handler.process.join("\n")
```

Comment: Since we are doing [codereview.se] here: calling `new` without arguments and then setting up the object using setters is a code smell. Objects should be valid after construction, but in your case, a `UserInputProcessor` instance would blow up with `NoMethodError`s for `nil` all over the place if you tried to use it directly after constructing it. And a minor one: `puts` already treats `Array`s specially by printing the elements line-by-line, there is no need for that call to `join` on the last line. `to_i` ignores everything after a number at the beginning of the string, no need to `chomp` it.